# How to multiply doubles in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

We are playing around with EAN13-barcodes and checking if the number format is correct. And when it is we want to get the number out in the proper format. We get the compile error: **"Expected: end of statement"** when we try this.
The error occurs in the "*weight = first...*" calculations in the code.

Any idea what might be wrong? Tried to google the error and we didn't find anything applicable to our situation.

```
Dim first As Double
Dim second As Double
Dim third As Double
Dim fourth As Double

If Left(data, 5) = 3 Or Left(data, 5) = 4 Or Left(data, 5) = 5 Then
' Checking if it's a weight and then converting the string to double
        first = CDbl(Val(Left(data, 12)))
        second = CDbl(Val(Left(data, 13)))
        third = CDbl(Val(Left(data, 14)))
        fourth = CDbl(Val(Left(data, 15)))

        If Left(data, 5) = 3 Then
        ' 1,234 kg
            weight = first * 1 + second * 0,1 + third * 0,01 + fourth * 0,001
        ElseIf Left(data, 5) = 4 Then
        ' 12,34 kg
            weight = first * 10 + second * 1 + third * 0,1 + fourth * 0,01
        ElseIf Left(data, 5) = 5 Then
        ' 123,4 kg
            weight = first * 100 + second * 10 + third * 1 + fourth * 0,1
        End If
    End If

End If
```

Comment: Try replacing the `,` with `.` in the fractional values

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Oh god...why didn't we think of this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the commas with periods. Vb6 isn't recognizing then as decimal separators. `0,1` should be `0.1` etc

Answer (score 2):

Format for double literals in VB6 is `1.1`. You used a comma as fractional separation, and vb6 doesn't accept that.